# Dart : Class Constructor not called

Tags: dart

I have following code :

```dart
class Article {
    String title;
    String contentString;
    Content content;
    
    Article(String title, String contentString) {
        this.title = title;
        this.content = contentString;
        //I want to call function here
    }

    Article.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : title = json['title'],
        contentString = json['content'];

    void _someFunction() {
       //create function to generate the Content
    }
}

class Content {
  final String text;
  final bool isLink;

  Content({this.text, this.isLink});
}
```

What i want to achieve is calling a function when the class is initialized. I tried to debug and add break point but it's not triggered. Is it possible to call a function when the class is initialized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any code you put at the `//I want to...` point should be called when the `Article` constructor is called. It won't be called if the `Article.fromJson` constructor is called instead. I'm *guessing* that's what's happening since you haven't said how you constrcut the `Article`s.

Consider changing the `fromJson` constructor to:

```dart
  Article.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : this(json['title'], json['content']);
```

This is a *redirecting generative constructor*, which means it forwards to the `Article` constructor, and all code run by that will also be run when using `Article.fromJson`.

Comment: Hi @Irn thanks for helping out. It's working !